# Ubuntu Server - How do I run a persistent script at startup?

Tags: ubuntu, shell, systemd

I am trying to run a script in the background at startup on Ubuntu 20.04.3 Server. I have tried different combinations of &, nohup, and systemd configuration without success. Currently, if I run systemctl start on the service the output.log will be created and will be write protected. If I run `ps -aux | grep java` only grep is listed. If I run the script manually, it works but maybe is not in the background because I do not get the prompt again until I use ^C.

Script to run

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "${0%/*}"
pwd
if ! grep -q "eula=true" eula.txt; then
    echo "Do you agree to the Mojang EULA available at https://account.mojang.com/documents/minecraft_eula ?"
    read  -n 1 -p "[y/n] " EULA
    if [ "$EULA" = "y" ]; then
        echo "eula=true" > eula.txt
        echo
    fi
fi
if pgrep -x "start.sh" > /dev/null
then
    echo "Running"
else
    java -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -Xmx6144M -Xms4096M -jar forge-1.16.5-36.1.16.jar nogui > output.log &
fi
```

Service

```
[Unit]
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=nohup /usr/local/bin/FTB/startFTBServer.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: Your script is interactive. It must not be. Why are you using `nohup`?

Comment: @DanielB It shouldn't be interactive. It would ask for eula acceptance if it wasn't accepted already but it has been. I thought systemd might be starting the script then killing it and I thought `nohup` might stop it. Just one of many things I've tried to get this to work.